# Is "pushing at an open door" a common expression in English?

Tags: expressions, word-usage, phrase-usage

I'm not sure if the expression "pushing at an open door" is used and understood by a native English speaker.

Comment: Have you checked dictionaries?

Comment: https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/push+at+an+open+door

Comment: I've heard it, but it's not "common" in much of the US.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's "common" in British English - but I've heard it, know what it means, and also wouldn't say that it "uncommon"!

Answer (score 1):

[Vivid idiom](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/push+at+an+open+door) meaning that an action/initiative/task can be achieved easily because there is minimal resistance.

Apparently it's usage is on the up in both [British](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pushing+at+an+open+door&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpushing%20at%20an%20open%20door%3B%2Cc0) and [American](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pushing+at+an+open+door&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpushing%20at%20an%20open%20door%3B%2Cc0) English.

Comment: I've generally interpreted it to mean "useless action".

Comment: @HotLicks - OK!  Maybe it's more UK than USA - although  Ngrams suggests that it's used in both countries?  Here are two more links, reassuring me that I'm not making it up!!  https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/push-at-an-open-door, https://www.usingenglish.com/reference/idioms/pushing+at+an+open+door.html,

Comment: Hot Licks, not useless action, unnecessary effort. At least that's what it means to me (UK).

Comment: It seems to be using ‘open’ in the sense of being unlocked, rather than being physically open. Not having heard this before, my mind went to the latter, which makes the saying    completely ambiguous.

Comment: @NeilW - I'm not sure why you suppose that 'open' should mean 'umlocked'.  Particularly as this choice renders the phrase confusing.  Given the sense the idiom has, surely it is more straight-forward to suppose that 'open' means 'ajar'?